# MS Access Select top n query grouped by multiple fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is part 2 of a problem that was already answered by peterm on this board.  Thanks again peterm!

So I have code that will return the top 3 test scores for a given student.  My table looks like the following:

StudentID,      Test ID,       Score
1,1,           95
1,                2,           90
1,                3,           90
1,                4,           90
2,                1,           99
2,                2,           95
2,                3,           90
2,                4,           90

Thanks to peterm, I have the following code which will do this for me:

```
SELECT StudentID, TestID, TestScore
  FROM MyTable t
 WHERE TestID IN
(
  SELECT TOP 3 TestID 
    FROM MyTable
   WHERE StudentID = t.StudentID 
   ORDER BY TestScore DESC, TestID
)
 ORDER BY StudentID, TestScore DESC, TestID;
```

My new problem is now I need to add two new fields to the table for Subject and Year, so I need to find the top 3 scores for each Subject-Student-Year combination.  Once I have the top 3 scores for each combination, I need to average them so that I will have one averaged score of the top 3 scores for each student-subject-year combination.  Hopefully, I've explained this clearly enough without having to mock up another table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried to group by the new fields but that didn't work.  This is beyond my knowledge of sql at this point.

Comment: show your data structure, how have you added year and subject in your database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT StudentID, Year, Subject,  AVG(TestScore) AS AvgScore
  FROM
(
  SELECT StudentID, Year, Subject, TestScore
   FROM MyTable t
   WHERE TestID IN
  (
   SELECT TOP 3 TestID 
     FROM MyTable
    WHERE StudentID = t.StudentID
      AND Year = t.Year
      AND Subject = t.Subject
    ORDER BY TestScore DESC, TestID
  )
) q
 GROUP BY StudentID, Year, Subject
 ORDER BY StudentID, Year, Subject;
```

Sample output:

```
| STUDENTID | YEAR | SUBJECT | AVGSCORE |
|-----------|------|---------|----------|
|         1 | 2012 |       1 |       91 |
|         1 | 2012 |       2 |       84 |
|         2 | 2012 |       1 |       94 |
|         2 | 2012 |       3 |       95 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dfa5e/5)** demo.
*Demo as usually is for SQL Server but expected to work in MS Access, maybe with minor syntactic tweaks*

Comment: What if the top scorer is 4 or more different StudentID having the same Year, Subject and TestScore?

Comment: Peterm, you are a god!  Thankyou, thankyou, thankyou!  Any tips on a good website to learn more about sql?  I would like to figure out this logic when I have more time.

Comment: Jade - thank you for your post.  What I'm looking for is to calculate the avg score of the top 3 tests for each student for each subject and year.  So, a student may take 10 tests in English in 2013 and another 10 in Geometry for the same year.  I want an output of 2 records for that student - one for Geometry in 2013 and one for English in 2013.  The first value would take the top 3 English test scores and average them.  The 2nd would do the same for Geometry.