# Top 3 per group including 0

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table for which I want to return the top 3 records by ErrorMargin per week commencing in Access 2010.

The problem I'm having is that 0 values are being ignored and I'd like to see just 1 record in the case of ties where the tie would take the total number of records over 3.

The table I have is:
*NB: VBA at bottom of post to create the table.*

```
 TMID   WeekCommencing  ErrorMargin
    1   05-Oct-15   0
    1   12-Oct-15   2
    3   05-Oct-15   1
    3   12-Oct-15   1
    8   12-Oct-15   2
    9   05-Oct-15   0.333333333
    9   12-Oct-15   4
    12  05-Oct-15   0
    12  12-Oct-15   1.5
```

The SQL I have at the moment is:

```
SELECT      T1.TMID,
            T1.WeekCommencing,
            T1.ErrorMargin,
            COUNT(*)
FROM        qry_REP_ErrorMargin T1 INNER JOIN qry_REP_ErrorMargin T2 ON
                T1.ErrorMargin <= T2.ErrorMargin AND
                T1.WeekCommencing = T2.WeekCommencing
GROUP BY    T1.TMID,
            T1.WeekCommencing,
            T1.ErrorMargin
HAVING      COUNT(*) <= 3
ORDER BY    T1.WeekCommencing,
            T1.ErrorMargin
```

This returns the following table, which is only showing two records for the 5/10/2015 - there are two further records with a 0 ErrorMargin and I'd like it to return one of those as well.  It doesn't matter which.
The TMID and WeekCommencing fields would make up the key field for the table.

```
TMID    WeekCommencing  ErrorMargin Expr1003
9       05/10/2015      0.33        2
3       05/10/2015      1           1
1       12/10/2015      2           3
8       12/10/2015      2           3
9       12/10/2015      4           1
```

I've had a play around with other solutions, but haven't managed to get anything to work yet - [MS Access Select top n query grouped by multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059077/ms-access-select-top-n-query-grouped-by-multiple-fields)

---

VBA Code to create the table:

```
Sub Create()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb

    db.Execute "CREATE TABLE qry_REP_ErrorMargin" & _
        "(TMID LONG, WeekCommencing DATE, ErrorMargin Double)"
    db.Execute "INSERT INTO qry_REP_ErrorMargin" & _
        "(TMID, WeekCommencing, ErrorMargin) VALUES (1,42282,0)"
    db.Execute "INSERT INTO qry_REP_ErrorMargin" & _
        "(TMID, WeekCommencing, ErrorMargin) VALUES (1,42289,2)"
    db.Execute "INSERT INTO qry_REP_ErrorMargin" & _
        "(TMID, WeekCommencing, ErrorMargin) VALUES (3,42282,1)"
    db.Execute "INSERT INTO qry_REP_ErrorMargin" & _
        "(TMID, WeekCommencing, ErrorMargin) VALUES (3,42289,1)"
    db.Execute "INSERT INTO qry_REP_ErrorMargin" & _
        "(TMID, WeekCommencing, ErrorMargin) VALUES (8,42289,2)"
    db.Execute "INSERT INTO qry_REP_ErrorMargin" & _
        "(TMID, WeekCommencing, ErrorMargin) VALUES (9,42282,0.333333333333333)"
    db.Execute "INSERT INTO qry_REP_ErrorMargin" & _
        "(TMID, WeekCommencing, ErrorMargin) VALUES (9,42289,4)"
    db.Execute "INSERT INTO qry_REP_ErrorMargin" & _
        "(TMID, WeekCommencing, ErrorMargin) VALUES (12,42282,0)"
    db.Execute "INSERT INTO qry_REP_ErrorMargin" & _
        "(TMID, WeekCommencing, ErrorMargin) VALUES (12,42289,1.5)"

End Sub
```

Comment: why `9   |    05/10/2015  |    0.33   |     2` have count = 2 ??

Comment: btw your query return a different result using your data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00f48/1

Comment: What mean `top 3 for group` because you say doesnt care wich 0 go first. and you should have double 0. and then 0.333

Comment: Thanks for your comments Juan. I don't see what you mean by that record having a count of 2 and I don't think sqlfiddle is executing the SQL the same way that Access would as it's giving different results.  You're correct - for the 5th October should have 0, 0 and 0.333 but as I said in my post - it's ignoring 0's and it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following may do what you want:

```
SELECT em.*
FROM qry_REP_ErrorMargin as em
WHERE em.TMID IN (SELECT TOP 3 TMID
                  FROM qry_REP_ErrorMargin as em2
                  WHERE em2.WeekCommencing = em.WeekCommencing
                  ORDER BY em2.ErrorMargin
                 );
```

Note that in the case of ties, MS Access might return more than three rows.  It you do not want duplicates, then include an id column in the `ORDER BY` to prevent ties:

```
ORDER BY em2.ErrorMargin, em2.TMID
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. With the extra `ORDER BY` on the ID column it's returning exactly what I want - with the example data.  Just need to test it with various data sets and I'll post back in a couple of hours to accept the answer.