# Top n records per group sql in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, top-n

I am making some software that tracks the scores of a test. There are multiple users, the details of which are stored in a user table. There is then a progress table which tracks a score with the date and the user who's score it is.

I can already select the 3 most recent records for a chosen userID

```
SELECT TOP 3 Progress.LoginID, Progress.Score, Progress.[Date Taken]
FROM Progress
WHERE (((Progress.LoginID)=[Enter LoginID:]))
ORDER BY Progress.[Date Taken] DESC;
```

And I can show all the records grouped by LoginID

```
SELECT Progress.LoginID, Progress.Score, Progress.[Date Taken]
FROM Progress
GROUP BY Progress.LoginID, Progress.Score, Progress.[Date Taken];
```

I want to be able to show the 3 most recent records for each user in one query and I'm unsure of how to use nested queries/subqueries to do so.

The field names for the user table are:

```
LoginID   
Forename    
Surname   
DOB   
Guardian Forename     
Guardian Surname      
Telephone Number
```

The field names for the progress table are:

```
ProgressID    
LoginID   
Score     
Date Taken
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem a year ago:  [Top 3 per group including 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374489/top-3-per-group-including-0?noredirect=1)

Using the same approach, this will return the latest three dates for each LoginID - you may get more than three records if there are tied dates for the same LoginID.

```
SELECT  PR1.LogInID, PR1.Score, PR1.[Date Taken]
FROM    Progress AS PR1
WHERE   PR1.[Date Taken] IN (
                        SELECT TOP 3 PR2.[Date Taken]
                        FROM    Progress PR2
                        WHERE   PR2.LoginID = PR1.LoginID
                        ORDER BY PR2.[Date Taken] DESC
                        )
ORDER BY    LoginID, [Date Taken]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your statement without top ranking into brackets and do your ranking in a second step simple as that:

```
SELECT Top 3 step1.* 
FROM (<YOUR STATEMENT>) AS step1
```

The question is older but it might be a solution though.