# Top 5 records by group in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

The code below returns all records :-

```
SELECT b.BROKERAGE_NAME, q.VAL_DATE
FROM TBLQUOTESNEW q LEFT JOIN TBLBROKERAGESNEW b ON q.BROKERAGE_ID = b.ID
WHERE q.VAL_DATE Is Not Null
```

Is it possible to have the top 5 records for each `BROKERAGE_NAME` returned, where `VAL_DATE` is descending?

Included

```
    Brokerage A    02/10/2017
    Brokerage A    02/10/2017
    Brokerage A    02/10/2017
    Brokerage A    02/10/2017
    Brokerage A    01/10/2017
    Brokerage B    06/06/2016
```

Excluded (as not in top 5)

```
    Brokerage A    30/09/2017
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using `SELECT TOP 5` & `ORDER BY VAL_DATE DESC`, but that will only work if your dates have a different time range.  As it is 2/10/2017 will be first place and 30/09/2017 will be second.

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html, the Top n per group section

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Top n records per group sql in access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220690/top-n-records-per-group-sql-in-access)

Comment: Have to agree with @ErikvonAsmuth.  Was looking at how to do it and that was the post I found and I think the Allenbrowne link was the one I used to get the answer in the duplicate.

Comment: It is not a duplicate (not by me anyway)

Comment: @user1936588 Not by me doesn't mean it's not a duplicate. You're supposed to do your research into existing questions posted by others

Comment: If I was able to find an answer I was able to use, I would have done so, and not posted my question. I had already searched not was not able to adapt any code I found to match what I needed. I apologise for my lack of knowledge on the matter.

Comment: From what I can tell - untested - the adaptation would be `SELECT b.BROKERAGE_NAME, q.VAL_DATE FROM TBLQUOTESNEW q LEFT JOIN TBLBROKERAGESNEW b ON q.BROKERAGE_ID = b.ID WHERE q.VAL_DATE IN (SELECT TOP 5 q1.VAL_DATE FROM TBLQUOTESNEW q1 LEFT JOIN TBLBROKERAGESNEW b1 ON q1.BROKERAGE_ID = b1.ID WHERE b1.BROKERAGE_NAME = b.BROKERAGE_NAME ORDER BY q1.VAL_DATE DESC) ORDER BY b.BROKERAGE_NAME, q.VAL_DATE`.  I won't put as answer as I just copied the query from the duplicated link and changed the field and table names.

Comment: @user1936588 If you've found that answer, share an implementation of it and any errors you've found while trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 5 
      b.BROKERAGE_NAME,
      q.VAL_DATE
FROM 
      TBLQUOTESNEW q 
LEFT JOIN 
      TBLBROKERAGESNEW b 
      ON q.BROKERAGE_ID = b.ID
WHERE 
      q.VAL_DATE Is Not Null 
GROUP BY 
      BROKERAGE_NAME 
ORDER BY 
      VAL_DATE DESC`
```

Comment: This doesn't return the results as specified in the question. It returns the top 5 brokerages. Not the top 5 VAL_DATE's per brokerage.

Comment: That's because your sample data only has Brokerage A - he's probably done the same as I did and just copy your sample and work with that.  Completely ignored that you want it split by brokerage. :)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - Improved sample data :)