# MS Access select the Nth Highest value in a table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

So I have the following database format:

```
+------++------+
| ID   | Value |
+------++------+ 
| 1    |   5   |
| 1    |   2   |
| 1    |   8   |
| 1    |   1   |
| 2    |   2   |
| 2    |   3   |
| 2    |   6   |
| 2    |   10  |
| 3    |   1   |
| 3    |   2   |
| 3    |   5   |
| 3    |   3   | 
| 3    |   5   |
+------++------+
```

And I am trying to output the top 3 values of each ID. Like:

```
    +------++------+
    | ID   | Value |
    +------++------+ 
    | 1    |   8   |
    | 1    |   5   |
    | 1    |   3   |
    | 2    |   10  |
    | 2    |   6   |
    | 2    |   3   |
    | 3    |   5   |
    | 3    |   5   |
    | 3    |   3   |
    +------++------+
```

Is this possible to do in MS Access using SQL?

Comment: This looks like a top N per group Access question.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220690/top-n-records-per-group-sql-in-access) may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You need *correlation* subquery :

```
select t.*
from [table] t
where value in (select top 3 t1.value
                from [table] t1
                where t1.id = t.id
                order by t1.value desc
               ) order by ID asc, value desc;
```