# How to generate a Query in MICROSOFT ACCESS that shows maximum values of a repeated field

Tags: ms-access

I HAVE THE FOLLOWING QUERY:

[image: QUERY]

This Query represents the payments of students per semester. Each repeated line represents a semester. For example, CUADRADO RUSEIRA JUAN FELIPE is shown in 4 consecutive rows, where each row represents a payment for a semester. For this example, we have 4 payments therefore there are 4 semesters paid. The last field (Periodo Numero) is the semester in number form.

How can the Query only show the last semester paid? For example in CUADRADO RUSEIRA JUAN FELIPE, I want only the last row to show in the Query. Therefore, the row with number 4 as Periodo Number. I would need this for every student in the Query.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Top n records per group sql in access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220690/top-n-records-per-group-sql-in-access)

Comment: Create another query based on the first that groups by CODIGO and selects Max PERIODO NUMERO. Or you can use a subquery as well to accomplish this same thing (the original query would be subquery and what I suggested as new query would be outer query).