# Why is my Access Max() subquery not working?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access table in which I want to return a set of records, but only for the most recent date.

My data has 24 records with 12 of these have RECORD_DATE=#23/04/2020#, the other 12 have RECORD_DATE=#24/04/2020# (ie. 12 with 23-April, 12 with 24-April); the field is set as Date/Time.

I have written a subquery to get the Max date for each record.

The problem I have is that my query executes, but returns all the records in the table (well, it applies the "WHERE Q.SITE_ID=?" correctly), not just those with the MAX(RECORD_DATE).

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT 
    Q.CONSUMABLE_RECORD_ID,
    Q.SITE_ID,
    Q.CONSUMABLE_STORAGE_ID,
    Q.CONSUMABLE_PRODUCT_ID,
    Q.CONSUMABLE_MEASUREMENT_UNIT_ID,
    Q.RECORD_DATE,
    Q.RECORD_VALUE,
    Q.LAST_DATE,
    Q.LAST_VALUE 
FROM 
    CONSUMABLE_RECORD AS Q 
WHERE 
    Q.SITE_ID =? 
AND 
    Q.RECORD_DATE=
    (
    SELECT 
        MAX(S.RECORD_DATE) 
    FROM 
        CONSUMABLE_RECORD AS S 
    WHERE 
        Q.CONSUMABLE_RECORD_ID=S.CONSUMABLE_RECORD_ID
    )
```

If it makes any difference, CONSUMABLE_RECORD_ID is the Primary Key, and I am executing the query using and OleDbCommand via C#, and the data provider I am using is Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0.  I've also tried using MAX(CONSUMABLE_RECORD_ID) in the subquery, but that didn't work - I'd prefer to keep it as Max(RECORD_DATE) as theoretically records could be entered out-of-sequence on date.

What do I need to do to get this working?  I tried 'TOP 1' in the subquery, and still get the 24 rows back.

I would prefer to keep this as a subquery rather than an Inner Join etc.

Edit:
This is different from [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220690).  In that one, they are looking for the top 3 results in a group - I just want the maximum record.  I tried adding TOP 1 to the start of the question, and and ORDER BY (which necessitates a GROUP BY), but I'm still getting all the records back.

Edit 2:
Sample Data:
[image: Sample data and structure]

The desired result is just all the records with RECORD_DATE=#24/4/20#.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Top n records per group sql in access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220690/top-n-records-per-group-sql-in-access)

Comment: Part of issue might be international date structure in parameter. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Comment: How would I fix that?  I'm not passing the data as a parameter (and it works fine using OleDbParameter anyway, in other code).  I tried max(CONSUMABLE_RECORD_ID) which should work (and if it did, would confirm that it is a date format issue), but that doesn't work.  Suggests that there is something fundamental about the subquery structure.

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that you don't want a correlated subquery.  This seems like a concise way of writing what you want:

```
SELECT cr.*
FROM Consumable_Record as cr
WHERE cr.Site_ID = ? AND
      cr.Record_Date = (SELECT MAX(cr2.Record_Date)
                        FROM Consumable_Record as cr2
                       );
```

Note the use of *meaningful* table aliases.  `Q` and `S` don't mean anything with respect to your data.  `CR` is an abbreviation for the table name.

The above will not return records if the site doesn't have any on that day.  If you want the most recent records *per site*, then use that in the correlation clause:

```
SELECT cr.*
FROM Consumable_Record as cr
WHERE cr.Site_ID = ? AND
      cr.Record_Date = (SELECT MAX(cr2.Record_Date)
                        FROM Consumable_Record as cr2
                        WHERE cr2.Site_Id = cr.Site_Id
                       );
```

I suspect this is what you really want.

Comment: Thanks.  I take the point re meaningful table aliases, but I chose Q and S for Query and Subquery.  My code is actually dynamic, similar to an entity framework, so I want a generic query where I can call  method where I pass the table name and the field that I want to use in the Max() subquery.

Comment: So for the constraint in the subquery, I think I now understand why, in my example, joining on the primary key means that every record gets returned.  Does this mean that it attempts to find the Max(record_date) for every single record in the main query, hence I just get everything back?

Comment: @ainwood . . . Basically yes.  Your correlation clause chooses one record.  The dates match on that record, so everything ends up being selected -- one comparison at a time.

Answer (score 1):

As @June7 has suggested, you can use TOP in the sub-query:

```
SELECT Q.Consumable_Record_ID, 
    Q.Site_ID, 
    Q.Consumable_Storage_ID, 
    Q.Consumable_Product_ID, 
    Q.Consumable_Measurement_Unit_ID, 
    Q.Record_Date, 
    Q.Record_Value, 
    Q.Last_Date, 
    Q.Last_Value
FROM Consumable_Record Q
WHERE Q.Site_ID=?
AND Q.Record_Date=(SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 R.Record_Date FROM Consumable_Record R ORDER BY R.Record_Date DESC);
```

Regards,

Comment: When I first tried this, I changed `Max()` to `Distinct Top 1` in my query, and still got all the records back.  I then tried your SQL direct, and it worked.  SO I looked at what else was different.  `AS S` vs just declaring the alias `S` made no difference, so I removed `WHERE Q.CONSUMABLE_RECORD_ID=S.CONSUMABLE_RECORD_ID`, and then it worked.  I removed that in my original Max() query, and it worked correctly there too.  Thanks for the steer - any explanation of why the join in the subquery is **not** required?

Comment: If you think about what you are asking the sub-query to return, you are asking it to return the most recent date - you don't actually care (in the sub-query part at least) about anything else.