# Writing a subquery to sort with a different field a group based on a sum in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, subquery

I have a data table that looks like this:

| Landing Page | Keyword | Sessions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Landing Page 1 | Keyword 1 | 26 |
| Landing Page 1 | Keyword 2 | 4 |
| Landing Page 2 | Keyword 1 | 6 |

There are multiple `Landing Page`s and `Keyword`s. Both are dimensions and text fields. `Sessions` is the amount for each of those dimensional values.

I'm trying to see the top 15 `Landing Page`s measured by descending sum of `Sessions` and the top 15 `Keyword`s measured by descending sum of `Sessions` just for those 15 `Landing Page`s.

In my query, I'm trying to group on `Landing Page`s and `Keyword`s. I believe this can be done with a subquery but I'm having trouble writing it.

Query #1 looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 15 Table1.[Landing Page], Sum(Table1.Sessions) AS SumOfSessions
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.[Landing Page]
ORDER BY Sum(Table1.Sessions) DESC;
```

Query #2 looks like this:

```
SELECT Query1.[Landing Page], Query1.SumOfSessions, Table1.Keyword, Sum(Table1.Sessions) AS SumOfSessions1
FROM Query1 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Query1.[Landing Page] = Table1.[Landing Page]
GROUP BY Query1.[Landing Page], Query1.SumOfSessions, Table1.Keyword
ORDER BY Sum(Table1.Sessions) DESC;
```

It seems like I just need some help adding a subquery to Query #2 that selects only the top 15 `Keyword`s for those top 15 `Landing Page`s. Inner joining to the first query provides the top 15 `Landing Page`s.

Based on my example data and considering only top 1 for both `Landing Page` and `Keyword`, I expect the results to look like this:

| Landing Page | Keyword | Sessions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Landing Page 1 | Keyword 1 | 26 |
| Landing Page 2 | Keyword 1 | 6 |

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired output as text tables.

Comment: @June7 done. Thanks!

Comment: Not much of a data sample. I doubt Keywords all start with "Keyword". Appears to simply pull TOP 1 Sessions for each LandingPage. Involves a nested query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220690/top-n-records-per-group-sql-in-access or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results