# Need to Find the most current Record for a person

Tags: ms-access

I am working with Access, dated I know but it is what I have.  I am dropping payment information into a table so I have multiple entries for each person.  All I want is a way to show the most recent entry for each patient and I way to mark them as current or delinquent.  I have been doing this manually but there must be a better way.  And I then need to pull reports off of those numbers.

Help!

I have tried a Max Query but then I cannot type in the query boxes and thus the point is defeated.

Comment: What determines delinquent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Top n records per group sql in access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220690/top-n-records-per-group-sql-in-access)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74524646/msaccess-query-to-return-result-set-of-earliest-rows-with-a-unique-combination/74525068#74525068