# Retain all the records grouped by an ID comparing only the values with similar strings within the group that has the minimum value

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-like

Given this data:

`Bolt_Table`:

| PID | UNIQ ID | GROUP_ID | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PID_24_2225 | 14 | 13 | 1141 |
| PID_5_1444E | 3214 | 13 | 652 |
| PID_5_14454 | 3152 | 13 | 802 |
| PID_24_2225 | 15 | 14 | 1141 |
| PID_5_14454 | 3151 | 14 | 802 |
| PID_5_1444E | 3213 | 14 | 652 |
| PID_26_21FC | 536 | 2300 | 597 |
| PID_5_13388 | 4121 | 2300 | 620 |
| PID_5_13382 | 4169 | 2300 | 802 |

This is the desired result:

| PID | UNIQ_ID | GROUP_ID | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PID_5_1444E | 3214 | 13 | 652 |
| PID_5_1444E | 3213 | 14 | 652 |
| PID_5_13388 | 4121 | 2300 | 620 |

Explanation:

- 1st Record: `@Group ID = 13`,

  Get the similar PID

  `PID_5_1444E` and `PID_5_14454` - compare the corresponding distances minimum of (652 and 802). Since 652 is the least, the corresponding PID: " PID_5_1444E " should be retained, hence record 1 of the desired table

What would be the query for SQL? (Microsoft Access)

I tried using LIKE, MID(String,1,4), GROUP BY & HAVING but nothing seems to work. How should I make the query for this?

The closest one I got is when I force to do the judging under a **hard coded GROUP_ID**,I would like to do it FOR EACH GROUP_ID

```
SELECT TOP 1 PERCENT PID, UNIQ_ID, GROUP_ID, Distance
FROM
(
SELECT
a.PID, a.UNIQ_ID, a.GROUP_ID, ID, a.Distance,
(select count(PID) as counter from Bolt_Table where GROUP_ID = a.GROUP_ID and LEFT(PID, 9) = LEFT(a.PID, 9)) as counter from Bolt_Table a WHERE a.GROUP_ID = 13
)
where counter > 1 
order by Distance
```

Comment: Hey Just selecting the lowest distance record doesn't per group doesn't work for you?Identifying and calculating similar rows is tricky in SQL.

Comment: this is the code to get lowest distance record for each group `SELECT  * FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GROUP_ID ORDER BY DISTANCE) AS RN FROM TABLE1
) XX
WHERE RN = 1`

Comment: Access does not support Row_Number().

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Top n records per group sql in access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220690/top-n-records-per-group-sql-in-access)

Comment: I was able to figure out similar PIDs. I have posted the code in the description. The only problem now is how to make that code work for every bolt ID

Answer (score 0):

SELECT b.pid, b.[uniq id], b.group_id, b.distance FROM bolt_table as b INNER JOIN (SELECT group_id, min(distance) as mindist FROM bolt_table GROUP BY group_id) as a on b.group_id = a.group_id AND b.distance = a.mindist

Comment: Close, what you did was to get the minimum per Group_ID, but we have to take note that the requirement is to get what is only "Similar" within that group ID. Take a look at the record WHERE PID=PID_26_21FC, it is the minimum in the group but it is not in the desired table since only those who are similar should be compared. In that Group (Group_ID=2300), only PID_5_13388 and PID_5_13382 should be compared.