# Having trouble with MS Access percentile query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-query

I have a MS Access table with a Category field and DollarAmount field.

I'm trying to query the table where it groups the data by Category and then shows the 10th percentile of the DollarAmount for each Category.

I used the below SQL and it works but it's dreadfully slow due to it using a subquery (I'm assuming). I tried separating them but that didn't work, because it purely showed the 10th percentile across the whole data set, and not by category.

Any alternate suggestions?

```
SELECT 
tblComplaints.Category, 
Max(tblComplaints.[DollarAmount]) AS 10thPercentileCalc

FROM tblComplaints

WHERE (((tblComplaints.[DollarAmount])
In (SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT [DollarAmount]
FROM tblComplaints AS sub
WHERE sub.Category= tblComplaints.Category
ORDER BY [DollarAmount] ASC)))

GROUP BY tblComplaints.Category;
```

Comment: Yes, correlated subqueries are known to perform slowly. Common topic. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220690/top-n-records-per-group-sql-in-access. Only alternative may be VBA writing data to 'temp' table.

Comment: Perhaps my article [20 Varieties of Quartiles](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33718/20-Varieties-of-Quartiles.html?preview=%2BptL2cPnHpk%3D) can help you.if you replace the quartile calculation with the percentile calculation. Full code is also at **GitHub**: [VBA.Quartiles](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Quartiles).