# setting displayed data limits in MSaccess

Tags: ms-access

I need to find the top five customers in each month from a query. I have tried the `Top Values` return property but it sets limits on the entire data displayed. I just want a limit for each month.

Query_Sample

[image]

Comment: Edit question to post attempted query statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Top 3 per group including 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374489/top-3-per-group-including-0)