# select top x by group in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a dataset like this

```
A  B  Group  Index
1  3   G1        25
1  3   G1        23
1  3   G1        99
4  5   G2        6
4  5   G2        8
4  5   G2        10
4  5   G2        2
4  5   G2        4
```

Ideal output is to pick **top x rows for each group with a descending order for `Index`**

```
Group  Index
G1      23
G2      6
G2      8
G2      2
G2      4
```

- For each distinct value in `Group`, values of `A` and `B` are identical for all rows.
- `B` indicates how many rows in the dataset. E.g. we have 3 rows for G1.
- `A` indicates how many rows needed for output. E.g. in the output only one row with lowest value of `Index` exists for G1 and 4 rows for G2

Can anyone shed some light on how to deal with this?

Comment: Is it possible to add a `row_number` for each row by group, then filter the records with `row_number <= A` ? But I have no idea how to add a `row_number` field in ms access.

Comment: I just found `DCount`. It may work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Top 3 per group including 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374489/top-3-per-group-including-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MsAccess can have a subquery as its select expression, which can be used to produce a limited rownumber:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT TblA.*, 
   (SELECT count(*) from Sheet1 TblB 
    where tblB.GROUP=tblA.GROUP and tblB.Index<=tblA.Index) as ROWNO
FROM Sheet1 TblA) Step1
where Step1.ROWNO<=Step1.A
```

Biggest caveat is that if two rows of the same group can have the same Index value.

Answer (score 1):

A single subquery will do:

```sql
SELECT 
    YourTable.Group, 
    YourTable.Index
FROM 
    YourTable
WHERE 
    (Select Count(*) From YourTable As T 
    Where T.Group = YourTable.Group And T.Index <= YourTable.Index) <= [A]
ORDER BY 
    YourTable.Group, 
    YourTable.Index DESC;
```

This assumes, that the values of `Index` are unique for each group.

[image]